# Filter hosts using a variable from with_items in ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I have the following set up for Ansible, and I would like to parameterize a filter that will loop, and filter out specific hosts.

```
- name: run on hosts
  hosts: "{{ item }}"

  roles: 
    - directory/role-name

  with_items:
    - us-east-1a
    - us-east-1b
    - us-east-1c
```

The result would be that the role called `role-name` would be first run on `us-east-1a` hosts, then `us-east-1b`... etc.

The above simple errors out with

```
ERROR! 'with_items' is not a valid attribute for a Play
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do, which is chunking my host list into groups, and running the same role against them, one at a time?

The following achieves the result I am looking for, but is clunky, and not dynamic in length.

```
- name: run on us-east-1a
  hosts: "us-east-1a"
  roles:
    - my-role


- name: run on us-east-1b
  hosts: "us-east-1b"
  roles:
    - my-role


- name: run on us-east-1c
  hosts: "us-east-1c"
  roles:
    - my-role
```

Comment: I'm trying to loop over groups of hosts, by availability zones, one at a time. So all of my us-east-1a first, and then 1b... etc.

Comment: `by availability zones, one at a time`

Comment: Help to be clearer if I'm missing something, but I am simply trying to run the same role against a `group of hosts`, one at a time. So instead of clumping the above into three different runs... I would like to filter the hosts out for targeted availability zones, at each iteration.

Comment: Have you tried to dynamically build an inventory group and reference this group in the next playbook? (see http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/list_of_inventory_modules.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to (1) have a common code and (2) serialise play execution per group of hosts (with targets inside a group running in parallel) would be to split your playbook into two:

`playbook-main.yml`

```
---
- import_playbook: playbook-sub.yml
  vars:
    host_group_to_run: us-east-1a
- import_playbook: playbook-sub.yml
  vars:
    host_group_to_run: us-east-1b
- import_playbook: playbook-sub.yml
  vars:
    host_group_to_run: us-east-1c
```

`playbook-sub.yml`

```
- hosts: "{{ host_group_to_run }}"
  roles:
    - my-role

  # other common code
```

---

<sup>If you wanted to serialise per host, then there is a [`serial` declaration](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size) that might be used in conjunction with [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47098071/2947502), but despite your comments and edit, it's unclear because once you refer to `us-east-1a` as a "host" in singular form, other times as a "group of hosts" or an "availability zone".</sup>

Comment: OK... I think this accomplishes what I am looking for. Yeah I caught the `host` issue and edited it. The `us-east-1a` is a filter for a group of hosts. I don't need them to run serially, just in chunks as I think your answer accomplishes here.

Answer (score 0):

Will [host patterns](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_patterns.html) do the job?:

```
- name: run on us-east-1a
  hosts: us-east-1a,us-east-1b,us-east-1c
  roles:
    - my-role
```

Update: @techraf has opened my eyes with his comment – host pattern alone will not do the job.
It will just concatenate all hosts from all groups.
But in a *predictable* way, which in some cases can be used to iterate hosts in every group separately.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44670007/2795592) for details.

Comment: I can check that... will that group them one at a time?

Comment: It should. At least for Ansible 2.3 it was the case.

Comment: I would have to add extra tags... so it would look something like this... `hosts:"tag_Name_value:&us-east-1a,tag_Name_value:&us-east-1b"`

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov "*will that group them one at a time?*" - "*It should.*" -- how come? It will create a set of hosts from a concatenation of the three groups and run against this result, not sequentially against hosts in each of the groups.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes. It will create a "sorted" set: all hosts from first group, then all hosts from second group and so on.